# is there a way to pass the output of a function as input to another function?

Tags: python

I am trying to create 2 functions.
Function1: "choices", returns 2 strings "choice_a,choice_b", which I would like to use as input
for Function2:"game"

how can I do this? what is wrong in this code?
thanks

```
def inserimento():
    plays=int(input("how many games do you want to play? \n"))
    while plays>0:
        general()
        plays =-1
    return plays

def general():
    #choices()
    game(choices())

def choices():
    choice_a=input("A: rock, scissor or paper? \n")
    choice_b=input("B: rock, scissor or paper? \n")
    return choice_a,choice_b

def game(a,b):
    if a == "rock":
        if b=="rock":
            choices()
        else:
            print("A won!")
    elif a== "scissor":
        if b=="scissor":
            choices()
        elif b=="rock": 
            print("B won!")
        else:
            print("A won!")
    elif a== "paper":
        if b=="paper":
            choices()
        elif b=="rock": 
            print("B won!")
        else:
            print("B won!")
    else:
        print("")

inserimento()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!   Your code will call "choices" twice; drop the first call to it in "general".

Comment: What is `game()`?  What parameters does it expect?  What's wrong with doing `game(choices())`?

Comment: what's the error you are getting?

Comment: thanks a lot! I see now where the error is, thanks for clearing :)

Answer (score 1):

```
def general():
    choices() # you don't need this function call here
    game(choices())

def choices():
    choice_a=input("A: rock, scissor or paper? \n")
    choice_b=input("B: rock, scissor or paper? \n")
    return choice_a,choice_b  # return value is (choice_a, choice_b)
```

you get a `tuple`, `(choice_a, choice_b)` returned from the `choices` function.

I am assuming your `game` function takes two arguments, something like this:

```
def game(choice_a, choice_b):
    print(choice_a, choice_b)
```

The problem here is that you are passing one argument (choice_a, choice_b) which is a single tuple, but the game method is supposed to take two arguments.

You need to unpack the tuple if you want to use that, like below:

```
game(*choices())
```

because `choices()` will return `(choice_a, choice_b)`, you can unpack it using the `*` operator.

Here is the complete code that you might find helpful:

```
def general():
    game(*choices())

def game(choice_a, choice_b):
    print(choice_a, choice_b)

def choices():
    choice_a=input("A: rock, scissor or paper? \n")
    choice_b=input("B: rock, scissor or paper? \n")
    return choice_a,choice_b

general()
```

Comment: thank you very much Kaushal, I understand! great! it works now

Answer (score 0):

```
def general():
    return game(choices())

def choices():
    choice_a=input("A: rock, scissor or paper? \n")
    choice_b=input("B: rock, scissor or paper? \n")
    return choice_b , choice_b
def game():
    return choices();

general()
```

Answer (score 0):

If your function takes 2 arguments and the first function returns 2 variables (a tuple), you should use `game(*choices())` (note the `*`) instead of `game(choices())`

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple `return` values you can assign them to variables.

```py
def general():
    a, b = choices()
```

Example output:

```py
>>> print(a)
rock

>>> print(b)
scissors
```

And then you can use them as arguments:

```py
def general():
    a, b = choices()
    game(a, b)

def choices():
    choice_a=input("A: rock, scissor or paper? \n")
    choice_b=input("B: rock, scissor or paper? \n")
    return choice_a, choice_b

def game(a, b):
    print(a, b)
```